# Рow to add data from another table pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data:

[transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4STV.png)
[items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShOIL.png)

I need to create columns "item_category_id" in transactions data.

```
transactions['item_category_id'] = 0
s=0
for i in transactions.item_id:
    transactions['item_category_id'][s] = items.loc[items['item_id'] == i].item_category_id
    s+=1
```

But this code works too long. Please, help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.merge` to do what you want (assuming `transactions` and `items` are two pandas dataframes):

```
import pandas
transactions = pandas.merge(transactions, items[["item_id", "item_category_id"]], on="item_id", how="left")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
transactions.merge(items[['item_id', 'item_category_id']], on='item_id')
```

This avoids an explicit loop, and allows `pandas` to use more efficient code.